# Insert ScrollView into layout

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to add a ScrollView to this layout but when i add it the Button is positioned over the last EditText and i don't understand why. Anyone can help me to understand why and how can i fix? thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">           

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">               

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Titolo"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ems="10"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/album"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Album"/>  

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/album"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/album"
        android:layout_below="@+id/album"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ems="10"/>  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Artista"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/artista"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/artista"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artista"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ems="10"/>  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Genere"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/genere"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/genere"
        android:layout_below="@+id/genere"
        android:ems="5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/traccia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/anno"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Traccia"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ems="5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artista_album"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Artista album"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/artista_album"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/artista_album"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artista_album"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ems="5"/>   

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Salva"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Anno"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anno"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/anno"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anno"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="4"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
```

in here.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="Salva"/>
```